# Synchronized block inside synchronized method

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronization

I've a socket connect method in my class that's supposed to be called by only 1 thread at a time. Inside that synchronized method, I've a synchronized block based off an random object. I'm calling the synchronized connect method of my class from an Android service

**Problem:**
Sometimes the *app goes into non responding state if the socketIO connection takes longer to establish connection* **when the socket URL is not reachable**. I've no clue why this is happening.

```
class MyService extends Service {
    public void onStartCommand() {
       MyUtilClass.getInstance().init();
       MyUtilClass.getInstance().startSomeOSBroadcastListeners();
       MyUtilClass.getInstance().connectAsync();
    }
}

class MyUtilClass {

    private final Object tempObj = new Object();
    private MyUtilClass mUtilClass;

    public static MyUtilClass getInstance() {
        if(mUtilClass == null)
             mUtilClass = new MyUtilClass();

        return mUtilClass;
    }

    public void init() {
         startListeningSocketIoConnectEvent();
    }

    public MyUtilClass connectAsync() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
           connect();
        }).start();

     return this;
    }

    private synchronized MyUtilClass connect() {
        synchronized(tempObj) {

            mSocketIO.connect();
            tempObject.wait(); 
        }

       return this;
    }

    private void startListeningSocketIoConnectEvent() {

        mSocketIO.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                synchronized (mWaitLock) {
                    tempObj.notifyAll(); //releasing the lock
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The `tempObj` is only being used for socketIO connection phase afterwards it's not used.

Why does it sometimes go into ANR state? Is this implementation correct?

Comment: When a thread calls `connect()` what ensures that the `tempobject.notifyAll()` won't happen _before_ the caller enters `tempObject.wait()`? Are you aware that `o.notifyAll()` does not do _anything_ if there isn't already some other thread waiting in `o.wait()`?

Comment: Where you have created `tempObj`?

Comment: I'm aware of that but since network latency won't let that happen, I'm not too worried about it yet though I need to take care of it. Since the test is being performed when the socket url is not reachable, in this case, notifyAll never gets called but since everything is running on background thread, ANR shouldn't happen but it's still happening and that's confusing me

Comment: @AmitBera I'm creating it in the MyUtilClass class scope. Appologies I forgot to add it in the snippet above.

Comment: I believe you didn't added the exact code on which you are facing the problem? Like `getInstance` should be a static method. Can you please review your post again.

Comment: I just reviewed it & updated the code.

Comment: Re, "...network latency won't let that happen..." Never? Guaranteed? Or, did you mean _hardly_ ever? If your code isn't running on an RTOS, then how can you be sure that some hiccough--some high-priority OS thread that gets stuck for a moment--won't sideline the thread calling `connect()` for a second or so at just the _wrong_ moment? It's never fun when a threading-related bug sneaks past all your testing and then takes down somebody's high-volume e-commerce web site. (Don't ask me how I know!)